# Matlab Lotka-Volterra model - finding steady states

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I am currently using Matlab to recreate the Lotka-Volterra model. I have been asked to find the steady state of the model, and I am not sure what parameters to use

The differential equations I used are:

```
% Change in prey 
dxdt(1)= k1*x(1) - k2*x(1)*x(2);
% Change in predator
dxdt(2)= k2*x(1)*x(2) - k3*x(2);
```

According to my assignment guidelines,

```
n_Prey     = k3/k2
n_Predator = k1/k2
```

I am unsure how to calculate what values to use?

In addition, what should a steady state graph look like? Should there initially be oscillations, which decrease over time?

Comment: A true steady-state graph will be a flat line over time since "steady-state" is a scientific way of saying "all time derivatives are zero".  So you just need to solve your system for `x1` and `x2` when all `dxdt`s are `0`.  Oscillations and such will occur for dynamic simulations from non-critical (i.e., not steady-state) initial data, such as those obtained from a run of `ode45` with your system.

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer if you ask math.stackexchange.com/tour.  This is really a math question more than a programming question.

Comment: To my understanding, the steady state *changes* depending on the parameters used. The formula should hold for arbitrary values of `k1`, `k2`, `k3`.